# Why abelian groups instead of modules in Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, free-modules

I am studying Algebraic Topology, homology and cohomology to be concrete. I am reading\working through Hatcher, Rotman, Harper and sometimes I combine them with other books when none of them give a satisfactory answer to my questions.

Why Rotman, Hatcher, and most of the books I look at use free abelian groups when defining  singular (co)chains instead of using free modules over an arbitrary commutative ring with multiplicative identity?

Harper is the only one I know that does it with modules.

Hope the question is not off-topic. I just feel I am missing something.

Comment: I suspect it is as simple as: People often take Algebraic Topology before they encounter modules in any detail. The authors want keep their books accessible to the widest audience, and without discuraions into commutative algebra.

Comment: Also, the universal coefficient theorem shows that working over $\mathbb{Z}$ already gives enough information.

Comment: Actually they did, atleast I know Hatcher for sure, but  in the beginning it is easier to do work with $\mathbb Z$ .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that was the first thing that came to my mind but I was not sure about it. For example that was not clear when reading Tammo Tom Dieck book. But thanks anyway!